# Logical or instead of ternary

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator, logical-operators

I've a legacy script. This is a part from it:

```
var e = e ? e : event;
```

So, nothing wrong here. But I use ternary mainly for toogling. Can it safely be rewritten like this

```
var e = e || event;
```

Is there any hidden reason for not using this one?

Comment: I find the first more readable.

Comment: I find the second more readable, and there's been this exact dispute last month (I'll try to find it but it's going to be hard). Also don't forget the simplest `if (!e) e = event;`.

Comment: @Cthulhu Both expressions are very simple, so readability cannot be an issue here. It seems that you're not used to working with the `||` operator. It's used regularly for these types of checks. I'd ditch the parens, though.

Comment: Is `e` a parameter of the current function? If yes, there's no need to declare a variable with that same name via `var`.

Comment: @Kos `if (!e) e = event;` is the way to go. Unlike in OP's examples, here the assignment is only made if necessary.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas In terms of performance, they seem the same (ternary seems a tiny bit better). Somehow, the ternary operator makes the `test` clearer to me. Using the logical operator just seems unnecessary :D

Comment: @Cthulhu `x || y` reads: "*if x is truthy return x; otherwise, return y*". It's as clear and straight-forward as it can get. The ternary op. - `x ? x : y` - does the same thing, but it repeats the `x` name twice, so the logical op. is the clear winner here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your example `e` will be used if it is NOT a *falsy* value, such as `false, 0, "", null, undefined`. Otherwise `event` will be used. In your case this should be save.

But there is some danger in using more complex logical expressions instead of if-then-else (or ternary). Here is an example:

```
result = value > 10 && getA() || getB()
```

If the *guard* `value > 10` evaluates to `true` AND `getA()` returns a *falsy* value, then `getB()` will be returned. This is different from the if-then-else behavior, which would return the *falsy* result of `getA()`.

Answer (score -1):

Gotta be carefull with the second option, you're basically expecting that if 'e' is anything but false, it'll assign it to your local 'e', otherwise, you'll use 'event', but if, for instance, 'e' is "0", what would you want your local 'e' to have? "0" or 'event'? Because in your case, your local  'e' would end up with 'event' anyways.

Comment: OP's code implies that `e` is supposed to hold a reference to the Event object. Therefore, it's either an Object value, or `null`/`undefined`, so it's appropriate to do checks like `e || event`.

Comment: Btw, not anything but false, but anything but false, undefined, null, empty string, zero, or NaN.

Comment: The same thing happens in the first case as well.